# How can you actually keep DateTime.now() up to date?

Tags: datetime, flutter, dart

Im new to flutter and I was going to practice by making a basic digital clock app. I got the date on the screen until the variable wont refresh. Does anyone have any idea to keep the (DateTime now = DateTime.now();) variable up to date?

Answer (score 3):

I guess that the best option is to create a periodic with a duration of 1 second and store the date in the state

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  DateTime _dateTime;

  _getDateTime() {
    setState(() {
      _dateTime = DateTime.now();
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _getDateTime();
    super.initState();
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (_) => _getDateTime());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(child: Text(_dateTime.toString())),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Timer` class to repeat the execution of a function in whatever duration of time. Maybe every second in your case.

```
import 'dart:async';

main() {
  DateTime time = DateTime.now()
  const duration = const Duration(seconds:1); //duration is set to one second
  new Timer.periodic(duration, (Timer t) => setState((){
    time = DateTime.now();  
  }));
}
```

Here I am defining a DateTime variable called time, initializing it with the current time and then setting its state every second.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [datetime_loop](https://pub.dev/packages/datetime_loop) that provide builder that return the datetime every seconds, minutes, hours or days, based on `TimeUnit`

```
DateTimeLoopBuilder(
  timeUnit: TimeUnit.seconds,
  builder: (context, dateTime, child) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          width: 200,
          height: 200,
          color: Color((math.Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt()).withOpacity(1.0),
        ),
        Text('$dateTime'),
      ],
    );
  }
)
```